# How to make Enumerator loop file content tail recursively to avoid stack overflow exception

Tags: scala, tail-recursion, scalaz, enumerator, loops

Recently, I was playing with [Scalaz Tutorial: Enumeration-based I/O With Iteratees](http://blog.higher-order.com/blog/2010/10/14/scalaz-tutorial-enumeration-based-io-with-iteratees/) written by Rúnar

I have a question about the implementation of enumerating the file.

```
def enumReader[A](r: BufferedReader,
                  it: IterV[String, A]): IO[IterV[String, A]] = {
 @tailrec  
 def loop: IterV[String, A] => IO[IterV[String, A]] = {
    case i@Done(_, _) => IO { i }
    case i@Cont(k) => for {
      s <- IO { r.readLine }
      a <- if (s == null) IO { i } else loop(k(El(s)))
    } yield a
  }
  loop(it)
}
```

My understanding of the code: The enumReader is getting signal **Done** or **Cont** from **iteratee**, if it is **Cont**, it call loop recursively.

However, this loop is not **tail recursive**, I use annotation **@tailrec** with a compilation error.
So, I think the problem is if enumReader try to read a large file, it will have **stackoverflow exception**.

Also, the reason I think it is hard is because usually when we want to change normal recursion to tail-recursion, we would have some **accumulator** used in the parameter, but in this case, it is a function IterV[String, A] => IO[IterV[String, A]]

Edit:
Further, I think when Iteratee method like **Count** may have same **stackoverflow** exception as well.

```
def counter[A]: IterV[A,Int] = {
  def step(n: Int): Input[A] => IterV[A,Int] = {
    case El(x) => Cont(step(n + 1))
    case Empty => Cont(step(n))
    case EOF => Done(n, EOF)
  }
  Cont(step(0))
```

can someone tell me how to refactor this one ?

Many thanks in advance